# parted: create swap partition on gpt disk (one liner) not working

Tags: linux, scripting, swap, gpt, parted

I am trying to create a swap partition in my script using parted based on the Arch Linux guidance.
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Parted#Partition_schemes
Somehow it is always sort of skipping the file system type and instead using it as partition label.

**Running parted manually creates the correct filesystem, linux-swap(v1).**

```
root@NAS[~]# parted /dev/sdb
GNU Parted 3.4
Using /dev/sdb
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) mklabel gpt
Warning: The existing disk label on /dev/sdb will be destroyed and all data on this disk will be lost. Do you
want to continue?
Yes/No? y
(parted) mkpart
Partition name?  []?
File system type?  [ext2]? linux-swap
Start? 0%
End? 100%
```

**Running parted using the command below creates an "empty" filesystem and gives it the partition label "linux-swap".**

```
root@NAS[~]# parted /dev/sdb -s mklabel gpt -- mkpart linux-swap 0% 100%
```

**Comparison**

```
parted (manually) - CORRECT FILESYSTEM
=================
root@NAS[~]# parted /dev/sdb print
Model: QEMU QEMU HARDDISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 4295MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  4294MB  4293MB  linux-swap(v1)



parted (script command) - WRONG FILESYSTEM
=======================
root@NAS[~]# parted /dev/sdb print
Model: QEMU QEMU HARDDISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 4295MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name        Flags
 1      1049kB  4294MB  4293MB               linux-swap
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create swap space within the `parted` command. You can set up the partition label to indicate that it is swap but it isn't really:

```
dd bs=1M count=100 if=/dev/zero >/tmp/100m.img
  100+0 records in
  100+0 records out
  104857600 bytes (105 MB, 100 MiB) copied, 0.687057 s, 153 MB/s

lo=$(losetup --show --find /tmp/100m.img); echo $lo
  /dev/loop0

parted $lo --script --align optimal unit MiB mklabel gpt mkpart primary linux-swap 1 100% print
  Model: Loopback device (loopback)
  Disk /dev/loop0: 200MiB
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
  Partition Table: gpt
  Disk Flags:

  Number  Start    End     Size     File system     Name     Flags
   1      1.00MiB  100MiB  99.0MiB  linux-swap(v1)  primary
```

Now if the swap partition had been prepared, `mkswap` would warn that it has overwritten it, but it doesn't:

```
mkswap ${lo}p1
  Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 99 MiB (103784448 bytes)
  no label, UUID=1abc5a9d-9c2e-452f-be16-d63f7e8e6af1
```

Just to evidence an overwrite ("wiping old swap signature"), let's repeat the swap space preparation:

```
mkswap ${lo}p1
  mkswap: /dev/loop0p1: warning: wiping old swap signature.
  Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 99 MiB (103784448 bytes)
  no label, UUID=2af1524b-101b-4e30-bdc0-2dfcadc1cde8
```

Finally, tear down the loopback device and delete the temporary image file:

```
losetup -d $lo
rm -f /tmp/100m.img
```

The conclusion here is that `parted` does not (and indeed cannot) prepare a swap partition for immediate use.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding my issue! I am not trying to replace "mkswap" with "parted ...."! My issue is that in my script command parted is not creating the right partition layout (linux-swap) that mkswap would need!

Comment: I edited my first post. Please take a look at the last code box. There you can see that running parted manually creates the correct filesystem. Where as running parted with my script command creates the wrong filesystem.

Comment: @TheHellSite there is no "filesystem" for swap. You can specify the partition type (as I've done in my example) if you really want to, but `mkswap` doesn't care what partition type you specify

Comment: so swap doesn't care on what filesystem type it gets created on using `mkswap`? I could also create an ext4,fat32,... filesystem and `mkswap` would overwrite to the right filesystem?

Comment: There is no filesystem type for swap. There is a partition type that can be used to indicate the type of data written to the partition, whether that be a filesystem, a swap device, encrypted data, RAID, or something else

Answer (score 0):

Your `parted` command can be followed by `mkswap` to format the swap space:

```
sudo mkswap /dev/sdb
```

Comment: I know, but before that I need to have the parted command to create the right file system type. Which is not working.

Comment: @TheHellSite it has created the right partition type. You now need to create the swap on it

Comment: @roaima No it did not! Compare the outputs of `parted /dev/sdb1 print` in my first post. When manually creating it looks way different! The script command creates a linux filesystem partition with the partition LABEL "linux-swap".

Answer (score 0):

I guess in `mkpart linux-swap 0% 100%` you missed partition name between `mkpart` and `linux-swap` so the latter is used as partition name rather that filesystem type.